# Check if a specific tab page is selected (active)

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, tabpage

I am making an event to check if specific tab page in a tab control is active.

The point is, it will trigger an event if that tab page in a tab control is the currently selected tab. Any code that will give me what I need?

Comment: It has a `SelectedIndexChanged` event why not check your specific tab there and do your work

Comment: @Maxim:
Yup, Windows Forms:
System.Windows.Forms.TabControl and
System.Windows.Forms.TabPages.

Comment: @V4Vendetta, That makes the event trigger when the tab is changed into any tab, I want to make it just that specific tab.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Assuming you are looking out in Winform, there is a `SelectedIndexChanged` event for the tab

Now in it you could check for your specific tab and proceed with the logic

```
private void tab1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (tab1.SelectedTab == tab1.TabPages["tabname"])//your specific tabname
     {
         // your stuff
     }
}
```

Comment: You can also use the same method to select the tab: `tab1.SelectedTab = tab1.TabPages["tabname"]`

Comment: or simpler approach with `tab1.SelectedTab.Name == "tabname"`

Answer (score 33):

To check if a specific tab page is the currently selected page of a tab control is easy; just use the SelectedTab property of the tab control:

```
if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == someTabPage)
{
// Do stuff here...
}
```

This is more useful if the code is executed based on some event other than the tab page being selected (in which case SelectedIndexChanged would be a better choice).

For example I have an application that uses a timer to regularly poll stuff over TCP/IP connection, but to avoid unnecessary TCP/IP traffic I only poll things that update GUI controls in the currently selected tab page.

Answer (score 8):

in .Net 4 can use

```
if (tabControl1.Controls[5] == tabControl1.SelectedTab)
                MessageBox.Show("Tab 5 Is Selected");
```

OR

```
if ( tabpage5 == tabControl1.SelectedTab)
         MessageBox.Show("Tab 5 Is Selected");
```

Comment: Minus one: this doesn't add anything to the answers posted years earlier.

Comment: it does add. Direct comparison with the tabpage without relying on the name as string. so hence plus 1

Answer (score 5):

For whatever reason the above would not work for me.  This is what did:

```
if (tabControl.SelectedTab.Name == "tabName" )
{
     .. do stuff
}
```

where tabControl.SelectedTab.Name is the name attribute assigned to the page in the tabcontrol itself.

Answer (score 3):

I think that using the event `tabPage1.Enter` is more convenient.

```
tabPage1.Enter += new System.EventHandler(tabPage1_Enter);

private void tabPage1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("you entered tabPage1");
}
```

This is better than having nested if-else statement when you have different logic for different tabs. And more suitable in case new tabs may be added in the future.

Note that this event fires if the form loads and `tabPage1` is opened by default.

Answer (score 2):

This can work as well.

```
if (tabControl.SelectedTab.Text == "tabText" )
{
    .. do stuff
}
```