# Basic Tab Control

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Hi, this is really basic stuff but i can't seem to find a simple answer on the web. I'm using Visual Studio 2010, doing C# and I have two tabs in a basic tab control and a calculate button outside of the Tabcontrol, that I need to calculate different sums depending on which tab the user has selected.

My initial thought was to use an `if` statement along the lines of:

```
private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (tabControl.tab1.selected == true)
            {
                 MessageBox.Show("whatever");
            }
            else
            {
                 MessageBox.Show("doesnt matter");
            }
        }
```

Any help would be great as you can probably tell I'm very new to programming, so thanks for taking time to answer

Comment: Well, what does not work with the if-statement you provided? That seems like the most logical approach to me.

Comment: TabPage control has not selected property.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653036/check-if-a-specific-tab-page-is-selected-active-in-c-sharp check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (tabControl.SelectedTab == tab1)
            {
                 MessageBox.Show("whatever");
            }
            else
            {
                 MessageBox.Show("doesnt matter");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (tabControl.SelectedTab == tab1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("whatever");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("doesnt matter");
    }
}
```