# Execute an Angular function only if the current tab is active in the browser

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have an angular js function which should be called for every 2 seconds only when the current tab is open in the browser. Is there any way to check whether the current page is active in the browser.

```
  $scope.callAtInterval = function() {

      var url = "http://127.0.0.1/test";

        $http.get(url).success( function(response) {
           $scope.initial = response;

        },
         function errorCallback(response) {
          $scope.result=response;
                      });
}

$interval( function(){ $scope.callAtInterval(); }, 5000);
```

}

Comment: post your code !!

Comment: @sachila ranawaka I posted the code. Here for every 5 seconds the api call will be made and data will be updated. But i want to do tis only when the current tab is active in the browser.

Comment: show the html code also

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a specific tab page is selected (active)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653036/check-if-a-specific-tab-page-is-selected-active)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active)

Answer (score 2):

I think  below piece of code is self-explanatory

```
import { HostListener} from "@angular/core";

  @HostListener("window:visibilitychange", ["$event"])
    onVisibilityChange($event) {
        const isVisible = $event.target.visibilityState === 'visible';
        this.logger.info(isVisible);
        if (isVisible) {
            // tab is visible
        } else {
           // tab is not-visible
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

*You would use the focus and blur events of the window:*

```
$(window).on("blur focus", function(e) {
    var prevType = $(this).data("prevType");

    if (prevType != e.type) {   //  reduce double fire issues
        switch (e.type) {
            case "blur":
                // cancel your interval function
                break;
            case "focus":
                // emit your interval function
                break;
        }
    }

    $(this).data("prevType", e.type);
})
```