# c# - Checking if a specific material tab page is active

Tags: c#, winforms, material-design

I'm trying to check if a specific tab page is active in my tab control, in order to change some of the colors in my form.
I have checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653036/check-if-a-specific-tab-page-is-selected-active)! but the problem I'm facing now is that I'm using materialskin framework, and looks like the tab selectors of this framework have no SelectedTab property, so I couldn't use

`if(materialTabSelector1.Controls[5] == materialTabSelector1.SelectedTab)
    MessageBox.Show("Tab 5 Is Selected");`
or any other similar codes provided in the answers of that post.
maybe I can handle the mouse left button click on each of the tabs, but the selector does not have a click event for each of it's pages.

any other suggestions for doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came across this issue myself, for anybody else looking for the code:#

```
if (materialTabSelector1.BaseTabControl.SelectedTab == tabPage5)
                {
                  MessageBox.Show("Tab 5 Is Selected");
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

The TabSelector is just for Displaying the what Tab is Active, but it does not contain any Controls or logic behind it. But it has a BaseTabControl, which is pretty much a normal TabControl. In there you could apply your logic.